# wp-admin returns 404

Tags: login

I installed theme-my-login and after playing with it decided it wasn't for me. I logged out my dashboard, went to log back in and now my wp-admin returns a 404 error - what do I do?

Comment: I just re-installed it in the end, it wasn't worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could have tried this:

try checking your `functions.php` and `wp-login.php` file:- try to see if there is some blank spaces at the end -(after `?>`)